# content delivery vs virtual server

Tags: cdn, vps

I've been using a VPS from inmotion hosting for about 10 years , cost is about $1500 annually, which is rather expensive considering what i use it for. I have a small 1 page website that isn't visited much , my primary use is to host js , css and image files that fantasy football users can embed on their sites. I'd say there are about 2400 users of my files and they make https requests to my server about 12,000 times per day getting files that range from 50kb to 2mb.

What would be your recommendations ?

Comment: You certainly don't need to be paying over 1000 dollars a year for that amount of traffic. If you are getting 12k requests a day, a server with 8 gigs of ram should be fine.

Comment: Would hosting the js files in a CDN be better ? Those rates are like $20/month

Comment: JS files generally don't use up a ton of bandwidth. You could always look into Cloudflare which would cache static assets like that.

Comment: Setup a server running nginx on AWS Lightsail (https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/pricing/) and put Cloudflare CDN (https://www.cloudflare.com/plans/) in front of it.